# How to read MediaWiki API JSON response

Tags: json, cors, jsonp, mediawiki-api, wikimedia-commons

I am trying to search images on Wikimedia Commons, using MediaWiki API. Here is my requested URL with search params:

https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=allimages&format=json&aifrom=Dada

I am succeed to get response in JSON format, but I could not read it programmatically because:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

Any advice?

**UPDATE:**

I have added one more param to the url: `callback=JSON_CALLBACK`, which transforms response to jsonp format. Now it possible to use angular `$http.jsonp()` method also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use **`jsonp`**<sup>**1**</sup> as `dataType` to prevent the "*No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.*" error. Then it works :

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    url : 'https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=allimages&format=json&aifrom=Dada',
    success : function(json) {
        json.query.allimages.forEach(function(item) {
            $('<img/>', { src : item.url }).appendTo('#images');
        })    
    }     
})
```

Here I add each image to a `#images` `<div>` just for demonstration purposes.

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/52g2Lazw/**

<sup>**1**)</sup> JSONP stands for “JSON with Padding” and it is a workaround for loading data from different domains. It loads the script into the head of the DOM and thus you can access the information as if it were loaded on your own domain, thus by-passing the cross domain issue <sup>[**cite**](http://www.sitepoint.com/jsonp-examples/)</sup>.

Answer (score 1):

If you are accessing the Wikimedia Commons API **from a Wikimedia wiki**, you can use the `origin` parameter of the API and this way make the API setting [CORS headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS). E.g. on [en.wikipedia.org](https://en.wikipedia.org/), you could access the Commons API this way:

```
$.get('https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?' +
    $.param({
        format: 'json',
        action: 'query',
        list: 'allimages',
        aifrom: 'Dada',
        origin: location.protocol + '//' + location.host
    })).done(function() { /*...*/ });
```

It is generally safer to use JSON (a pure data format) than loading and **executing JavaScript** (JSONP) file that could, in theory, **do evil** with your visitors. I would probably set up a proxy server for this purpose, instead of using JSONP. A simple web search for `set up a proxy json` may result in plenty of useful results.

Comment: what about if you wanted to access the MediaWiki search API using plain javscript?

Comment: @BrianZ: In Browsers one would use [an XHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) and [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

Comment: I've got a working example of XHR and `JSON.parse()` here -- http://jsbin.com/gilunipiwe/edit?html,js,output . If you open your browser console you'll see that the example gets the response at the network level but suffers from "Cross-Origin Request Blocked". How can I get past this Cross-origin block in the jsbin example here?

Comment: @BrianZ One would have to set up a proxy that doesn't care about origins and itself sets a Cross-Origin header that would allow script from jsbin to read the response when not running the code from a Wikimedia wiki.